# Polynomials: irreducibility $\iff$ no zeros in F.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

Given is the polynomial $f \in F[x]$, with $deg(f)=3$. I have to prove, that f is irreducible iff $f$ has no zeros in $F$.

"$\Rightarrow$": let's prove the contrapositive: "if $f$ has zeros in $F$, then $f$ is not irreducible."

If $f$ has zeros in $F$, it means there's at least one zero and we can represent $f$ as product of two polynomials: $f = (ax + b) * q(x)$, where $deg(q)=2$. But for a polynomial to be irreducible, the only way to factor it into two polynomials is in a way that one of them is of degree $0$, i.e. it's not irreducible.

There are gaps in the prove which follows from some blind spots in my understanding of the material. Please, help.

QUESTIONS:

1) If a polynomial of degree 3 has a zero point, can I say, we can represent it in one of the following ways?

$f=(ax+b)q(x)\\
f= f = (ax+b)(cx+d)g(x)\\
f = (ax+b)(cx+d)(gx+h)$

What about polynomials of type $ax^3 + b$? I can also say that the zero point is $\sqrt[3]{-\frac ba}$. Which one should I use?

2) I saw people writing $(x - a)$ when they factor a polynomial or talk about zero points. If which cases I should use $(x-a)$ and $(ax+b)$ notations? Should I have used $(x-a_1)$ notaion in 1)

3) In my proof I do nothing with the fact that $deg(f) = 3$. I guess, this fact is given for some reason. Could you tell me please, what the reason is?

Sure, some people will find these question stupid and the answers straightforward, but I need your help to put every piece of information about polynomials on right places in my mind.

Answer (score 1):

1) If $f(a)=0$, then all you know is that $f(x)=(\square x+\square)g(x)$ for some $g(x)$. You do not know from this if $g(x)$ can be factored further,  so your other expressions are not generally valid. You also need to be able to *justify* how you know that $f(x)$ has a linear factor from the existence of a root.

It is true though that $f(x)$ will factor in one of two ways: a linear factor times a quadratic irreducible factor, or three linear factors. (Note that the second two factorizations in your list are actually the same, because $\deg f=3$.) You want to stick with the first factorization for your proof, because (a) it suffices and (b) it comes directly out of the application of the *factor theorem*.

2) The linear factor $x-a$ is technically of the form $\square x+\square$, but writing $x-a$ emphasizes the fact that you are using the *factor theorem* in your proof, and that you are using a zero (namely $a$) in order to construct the linear factor. For these reasons, writing $x-a$ is definitely better.

3) You have only done one half of the proof. You showed that if $f$ has a zero then it is reducible, and this fact actually does not depend on $\deg f=3$, as it's true for all polynomials. Now you need to show the other direction, that if $f$ is reducible, then it has a zero. Here you will use $\deg f=3$: if this is the case when $f$ is reducible, then what are the possible degrees of $f$'s factors?

Note that the originally problem asked you to show that $f$ is irreducible iff it has no zeros, and this is equivalent to showing $f$ is reducible iff it has a zero. This is because $\rm A\Leftrightarrow B$ and $\rm\neg A\Leftrightarrow\neg B$ are logically equivalent propositions (split the iff into two implications then use contraposition).

Answer (score 1):

If $f(x)$ is a polynomial and $g(x)$ is *any* nonzero polynomial, you can always write $f(x)=q(x)g(x)+r(x)$ with polynomials $q(x)$, $r(x)$, $\deg r<\deg g$ (polynomial division with remainder).
Especially, if you let $g(x)=x-a$ be a linear polynomial,you obtain $f(x)=q(x)\cdot(x-a)+r$ where $r$ is *constant*. If $a$ happens to be a root of $f$, observe that from $f(a)=q(a)\cdot 0+r$ you obtain $r=0$, i.e. $f(x)=q(x)(x-a)$. So if $\deg f>1$ and $f(a)=0$ for some $a\in F$, $f$ cannot be irreducible.

The property that $\deg f=3$ is needed for the other direction of the proof (For example $x^4-5x^2+6$ is reducible in $\mathbb Q[x]$ but has no root in $\mathbb Q$).
Assume $f$ is reducible, say $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ for some nonconstant polynomials $g,h$. What can you say about the degrees of $g$ and $h$?

Comment: if $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ then polynomials $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ must be of degree $1$ or $2$.  But we know that a polynomial is reducible, i.e. can be represented as a product of two polynomials, does it mean every of the factor-polynomials has a zero? If $deg(g) = 1$, then $g(x)$ is a linear polynomial and zero is equal $-\frac ba$, must be no problem in fields starting from rational numbers. What about $h(x)$ which is of degree 2?

Comment: And why can I not use the same reasoning for $f, deg(f) = 4$: if it's reducible, I can represent it as $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$, where $deg(g) = 1$ and $deg(h) = 3$. Or what it the difference in polynomials of grad 3 and grad 4 in this case? Could you help me please?

Comment: Tell me please, if my reasoning is correct:

in case of $deg(f) = 3$ we have ways to split the polynomial as a product of one and two degree polynomials. And there's always a zero point for a linear polynomial in a field, right? So we don't care about the one with degree 2 - it may, or may not have a zero. In case of $deg(f) = 4$ there's also an option to represent $f$ as a product of two 2-degree polynomials but there's not in every field a zero for a poylnomial of deg. 2, i.e. can happen, we can split it, but have no zeros.

Comment: One more question: what about polynomials of degree 5 and 6? Is the statement in my main question correct for $deg(f) = 5$ or $deg(f) = 6$. 

Is it that it's true for odd degrees and wrong for even?